# How to pass secrets to poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry

I want to reference a dependency in a private git repository which normally would look like this in the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
my-module = { git = "https://username:password@gitlab.com/something", branch = "branch" }
```

My question is how can I inject the password through environment variables or any other way I can use in my CICD. AFAIK poetry doesn't support environment variables, so basically looking for a workaround if you've been in the same situation.

Comment: there is a discussion about that [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/208), and summarizing "[this feature is an overhead](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/481#issuecomment-470277773)".

Answer (score -2):

you can set up ssh keys to authenticate with gitlab without a password,
and change your git url from https to ssh.

to do that, generate `id_rsa`, and `id_rsa.pub` files,
put them in `~/.ssh`,
and update your remote location with `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git`

can read more details here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: Thanks @lev, but `My question is how can I inject the password...` so I was intentionally trying to avoid ssh key. I ended up fixing it with git config; so still using passwords but not  as part of the modules' paths